# Right Align Flex Container

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to align a flex container to the right of the block it is in.

I'm using Magento 2.2.3

[image: Screenshot of page]

The container it is in has the following set:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
max-width: 1280px;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
width: auto;
}
```

my flex container and its divs.

```
#kidsaw-social-links {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
justify-content: flex-end;
background-color: red;
}

#kidsaw-social-links > div {
width: auto;
height: auto;
border: 1px dashed red;
}
```

I have the above set already and tried playing around with various things I am seeing on google but not having any luck.

If I set a width on #kidsaw-social-links it works but when shrinking my web browser, it doesn't scale for mobile.

```css
   .page-bottom, .footer .content {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 1280px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    width: auto;
   }
    #kidsaw-social-links {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   flex-wrap: nowrap;
   justify-content: flex-end;
   background-color: red;
  }
    #kidsaw-social-links > div {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px dashed red;
   }
    #kidsaw-footer {
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: row; 
    flex-wrap: nowrap; 
    justify-content: space-between;
   }
   #kidsaw-footer > div {
    width: auto; 
    height: auto; 
    padding: 10px;
   }
   #kidsaw-footer > ul {
   list-style-type: none;
   padding-left: 20px;
   }
```

```html
<div class="page-bottom">

<div id ="kidsaw-social-links">

<div><img title="Like us on Facebook" src="http://i.cubeupload.com/1Iy3Xm.jpg" alt="Like us on Facebook" width="68" height="76"></div>
<div><img title="Like us on Facebook" src="http://i.cubeupload.com/1Iy3Xm.jpg" alt="Like us on Facebook" width="68" height="76"></div>
<div><img title="Like us on Facebook" src="http://i.cubeupload.com/1Iy3Xm.jpg" alt="Like us on Facebook" width="68" height="76"></div>
<div><img title="Like us on Facebook" src="http://i.cubeupload.com/1Iy3Xm.jpg" alt="Like us on Facebook" width="68" height="76"></div>
<div><img title="Like us on Facebook" src="http://i.cubeupload.com/1Iy3Xm.jpg" alt="Like us on Facebook" width="68" height="76"></div>

</div>

<div class="footer content">

<div id="kidsaw-footer">

<div>
<h2>Store Information</h2>
<ul>
<li><a href="/">Homepage</a></li>
<li><a href="/">About Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div>

<h2>Support</h2>
<ul>
<li><a href="/">Contact Us</a></li>
<li><a href="/">Customer Service</a></li>
<li><a href="/">Orders and Returns</a></li>
<li><a href="/">Privacy and Cookie Policy</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div>
<h2>Store Tools</h2>
<ul>
<li><a href="/">Advanced Search</a></li>
<li><a href="/">Search Terms</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: try removing the nowrap value of flex-wrap property

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @FridayAmeh it does nothing.. I think the main container is stopping it. I set different values for the main container and it is pushing it to the far right of the screen but I want the last facebook icon to line up with 'Store Tools'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you can choose 1 of 2 ways. The first one to add 100% width to flex container and justify-content to flex-end;

```
#kidsaw-social-links {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background-color: red;
}
```

and the second one just to add margin-left: auto; margin-right: 0; to your container

Comment: adding width: 100% on the flex container does nothing, it just sits in the middle of the page still. I tried putting a container around the flex container and it still stays centered. At the top of my original post, If I change them values to margin-left: auto; and margin-right: 0; it is moving my whole homepage to the right.

Comment: Can you share some code snippet here? I'll adjust the answer to fit your code.

Comment: I've added a snippet to the bottom of my post now, but as the site I'm working on is Magento, the snippet actually works compared to what I'm working with.